# On Dev C++ compiler the output of the following code is 10,10 I am not able to understand how the value of a is assigned to b?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    a,b=(b,a);
    printf("%d, %d ",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the following code on dev cpp is 10, 10 I am not getting why?

Comment: Because you're abusing the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Examples).

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator separates expressions in a way similar to how the semicolon separates statements. The value of a comma expression is the same as the value of the last expression in the chain.

Your code snippet has two comma operators - one on the left and one on the right side of the assignment operator. The right side selects the value to be assigned - the last one in the chain, i.e. `a`. Since comma has lowest priority, assignment is parsed done to variable `b`, i.e. the assignment is equivalent to

```
b = a;
```

Expression `a` on the left side of the assignment operator has no effect, because it reads the value of `a` without making any changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator works like that. Your statements are:

```
a // no op
b = (b, // no op
    a)
```

and the value of (b,a) is the value of the last expression in the sequence of comma separated expressions, i.e. a, which is equal to 10.

Try this also:

```
printf("%d\n", (3,7));
```

Comment: Hi MK Thanks for the reply now when im trying to run the same code with 3 variables with the value 30 of third varible  like a,b,c=(b,a,c) it is printing 10,20,30 how thiis will work

Comment: this will not changing anything you will assign c = c

Comment: Akhilesh Arya, read what @user3386109 posted: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Examples). It has several examples.